# Two foreign keys referencing each other in Django

Tags: python, django

I have an Order model. I want to track each order's current state and which states it has been through.

Can I use

```
class Order(models.Model):
    current_state = models.ForeignKey('State')

class State(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
```

or is it better to use

```
class Order(models.Model):
    pass

class State(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    is_current = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I don't know if it's bad practice to have two foreign keys referencing each other.

Answer (score 0):

These are not "two foreign keys referencing each other" - which wouldn't mean anything - but "two models referencing each other".

There's no "better" solution here, depends on your exact specs and needs, but as a general rule, the simpler your model the better. If the "current" state is garanteed to always be the last one (you may want to have a `created_on` timestamp in your `State` model FWIW), then you don't need the `Order.current_state` FK nor even the `is_current` flag.

Also if you go for the `Order.current_state` FK, you'll have to make it nullable, else you'll have a chicken-and-egg problem...

Oh and yes: this is definitly not a Django or Python question, it' a relational model design problem.

Comment: I like the idea of getting the current state from the last created state object. But what if I want to filter all the orders by their state. I can make a function in my order model `def get_current_state(): return self.states.latest()` but I don't know how to use it in a queryset when it's not a field in the database. I cannot do `Order.objects.filter(get_current_state__type=1)`